# Is there a way to autoplay and loop an audio file on all pages of a site if I use frames?

Tags: html, css, audio, html5-audio

I want to make an audio file play looped while the user browses my site. I've already used frames to put a navigation pane on the left. I've tried to use  but it does not play.

Here is a link to my site: https://waxworm.neocities.org

Here's the html code for my navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Scott's corner</title>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scottstyle.css">
</head>

<style>
    
    html{
        background: black
    }
    .NAVBAR {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: black;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        line-height: 50px;
        border-right: ridge maroon;
        text-align: center
        }

</style>

<body>
    <div class='NAVBAR'>
        
        <img src="img/pool/sleep.gif"
             class="pagedoll"
             title="Hands off, tiger!">
        
    <div style="margin: 10px;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F91401, #600601);
                border: ridge black 5px;
                position: relative;
                top: 50px">
        <br>
        <div id="float" class="bubblelink"
             style="animation-delay: 0.2s">
            <a href="/home.html"
               target="center">HOME<br></a></div>
        <div id="float" class="bubblelink"
             style="animation-delay: 0.4s">
            <a href="/quotes.html"
               target="center">PROFOUND QUOTES<br></a></div>
        <div id="float" class="bubblelink"
             style="animation-delay: 0.6s">
            <a href="/links.html"
               target="center">COOL SITES<br></a></div>
        <div id="float" class="bubblelink"
             style="animation-delay: 0.8s">
            <a href="/stuff.html"
               target="center">STUFF I LIKE<br></a></div>
        <div id="float" class="bubblelink"
             style="animation-delay: 1s">
            <a href="/art.html"
               target="center">ART<br></a></div>
        <div id="float" class="bubblelink"
             style="animation-delay: 1.2s">
            <a href="/gifs.html"
               target="center">DEADPOOL GIFS<br></a></div>
        <br>
        </div>
        <p>.</p> 
<!--       ^^ the link box's scroll bar disappears when i put this here so Yeah-->
        <audio loop preload="auto" controls>
            <source src="anothermedium.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            </audio>
<!--        this doesnt work ^ -->
        </div>
</body>
```

In the stylesheet, I've made it so that audio elements are not displayed. I don't know if this is why the audio doesn't play. I've also tried to use scripts but since I do not know how to code in JS, nothing really changed.

I expected the audio to play on loop, but it doesn't work. Even uploading it to neocities to see if it's just Brackets acting up didn't change anything. What can I do instead?

Comment: as i can see in shared link you audio file path is invalid please check and update that

Comment: Thank you, hosted the file but it does not autoplay when I load up index.html. Is it because navbar.html is loaded into a separate frame?